# Uninstall all Visual Studio versions manually after _Instances folder was deleted

Tags: visual-studio, installation, instance, visual-studio-installer

Context:
I had an unrelated issue with my Visual Studio installation and saw in the "Visual Studio Installer" that it has a "Download cache" (for me C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages) under "Installation locations". I went on to delete the contents of this folder (don't do that!).

Now unfortunately the "_Instances" folder inside of it is gone as well. This apparently is the location where the "Visual Studio Installer" stores all information about the installed Visual Studio versions.

Now I have 3 versions of Visual Studio installed (2017, 2019, 2022 - all in Professional version), that I can't modify or uninstall anymore because the Installer doesn't know about them.

Ideally, I just want to uninstall them fully and start again with new fresh installations, but I don't know how to uninstall them manually.

Things that already didn't work for me:

- Control Panel -> Uninstall, this just opens the "Visual Studio Installer" and again it has no information anymore
- InstallCleanup.exe, seems to do something but the Visual Studio installations are still there after running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove Visual Studio manually, please delete following folders:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio`

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio`

`%programdata%\Microsoft\visualstudio\packages`

[Back up](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) and then delete following Registry keys(press Win + R, run `regedit`):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup`

After that download a new setup file, put it into a new empty folder and run it to reinstall VS.

Comment: I was finally able to remove it fully.
Deleting only the above registry keys did not fully remove the Visual Studio installations (such that they are no longer shown by 'winget list "Visual Studio"'), but I had success using the Revo Uninstaller 2.4.5 to delete all leftover registry entries.